# gcc: undefined symbols for architecture x86_64, missing vtable

Tags: c++, macos, gcc

I'm trying to do some basic c++ inheritance + abstract method program on my mac book pro 15 and the gcc information is below.

gcc:

```
mmcmbp:cpp-shapes abe$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Code:

```
/** 
 * @file main.cpp
 * c plus plus implementation of shape and triangle inheritance.
 *
 * @brief Shape and Triangle implementation
 *
 * @author abraham cabrera
 *
 * @version 1.00
 */
#include <stdio.h>

/**
 * @class Shape
 */
class Shape {
public:
  /** an enum of shape type
   *  Shape type representation
   */
  enum ShapeType { base, triangle };

  /* Default Shape constructor */
  Shape() {
    this->type = base;
  }

  /**
   * Shape constructor with type input.
   *
   * @param[in] type the shape type
   */ 
  Shape(ShapeType type) {
    this->type = type;
  }

  /**
   * Get type of Shape
   *
   * @return shape type
   */
  int getType() {
    return this->type;
  }

  /**
   * Mutator for setting the shape type.
   *
   * @param[in] type shape type
   * @return void
   */
  void setType(ShapeType type) {
    this->type = type;
  }

  virtual int area() {
    return 0;
  }
private:
  ShapeType type; //< Type of shape.
};

class Rectangle: public Shape {
public:
  /**
   * Rectangle Constructor 
   * 
   * @param[in] length length of rectangle
   * @param[in] width width of rectangle
   */
  Rectangle(int length, int width) : Shape(Shape::ShapeType::triangle) {
    this->length = length;
    this->width = width;
  }

  /**
   * Gets the length of the Rectangle.
   * 
   * @return length 
   */
  int getLength() {
    return this->length;
  }

  /**
   * Gets the width of the Rectangle
   * 
   * @return width
   */
  int getWidth() {
    return this->width;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the length of the Rectangle
   *
   * @param[in] length
   * @return void
   */
  void setLength(int length) {
    this->length = length;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the width of the Rectangle
   *
   * @param[in] width
   * @return void
   */
  void setWidth(int width) {
    this->width = width;
  }

  /**
   * Calculates the Area of a Rectangle
   *
   * @return length * width
   */
  int area() {
    return this->length * this->width;
  }

private:
  int length; //< The length of the Rectangle
  int width; //< The width of the Rectangle
};

int main()
{
  Rectangle rectangle = Rectangle(4, 3);

  printf("Rectangle %i\n", rectangle.area());
  printf("width %i, length %i\n", rectangle.getWidth(), rectangle.getLength());
  return 0;
}
```

I guess I'm not understanding c++ virtual functions correctly here because when I try to compile my little code snippet from above and I get the below errors and warnings.

```
mmcmbp:cpp-shapes abe$ gcc main.cpp -o main
main.cpp:71:51: warning: use of enumeration in a nested name specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
  Rectangle(int length, int width) : Shape(Shape::ShapeType::triangle) {
                                                  ^
1 warning generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for Shape in main-6841d5.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for Rectangle in main-6841d5.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Questions:

Clearly I'm not understanding the error portion which leads me to my first question.

1. What exactly does the error I get up above mean?

As for a side question, because I have been kinda curious.

2. Why am I getting the following warning `warning: use of enumeration in a nested name specifier is a C++11 extension`?

I really appreciate your most kind an gracious input.

Thanks,

-Abe.

Comment: If you use inheritance, you really should provide virtual destructors.

Comment: I think thay making function `area` in `Shape` class pure virtual will be better than returning 0

Comment: I updated my answer by showing how to compile using gcc driver not g++.

Comment: Also you should use clang in Mac as Apple stop using gcc from 4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are compiling with C maybe, use `g++`. Also include `<cstdio>` instead of `<stdio.h>` in C++.

Make a virtual destructor for your `Shape` class for 1:

```
 class Shape {
 public:
    virtual ~Shape() {}
    ...
 ;
```

Use `enum class` for your `enum` in question 2. Plain `enum`s are unscoped.

Use `-std=c++11` to make use of a more modern standard. GCC 6 already defaults to `C++14`.

Comment: The GCC frontend program `gcc` can compile both C and C++ files, it uses the file suffix to determine what kind of source it is. It will however not link with the C++ runtime library which is a problem here.

Comment: Wow, why didn't I notice this and I did not understand your second part of include. Do you mind rephrasing it? Thanks you very much Germán!

Comment: Use #include<cstdio> not #include<stdio.h> . Mac has quite old version of gcc.

Comment: Mac doesn't have *any* version of gcc.  It has clang (when you install the Xcode command line tools) and it's pretty up-to-date WRT LLVM's own version.

Answer (score 3):

You should use g++ as driver to compile c++ code.

```
g++  -std=c++11 ~/tmp/virt.cpp
```

Or

```
gcc -std=c++11 ~/tmp/virt.cpp  -lstdc++
```

But former is preferred

You need to pass -std=c++11 to disable this warning as by default gcc in Mac doesn't compile for c++11 by default.

Comment: Or better still `clang++`.

Answer (score 3):

1. You are using gcc to compile a c++ program. gcc is the GNU C compiler, you should use g++ to compile your program.

`g++ main.cpp -o main`

2. Enums in c++03 are not scoped, so you can't use enums like `EnumType::EnumValue`. In c++11 if can declare an enum like
   `enum class EnumType { EnumValue };` an then you would be able to use it like you intended. More info on enums [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)

Comment: The GCC frontend program `gcc` can compile both C and C++ files, it uses the file suffix to determine what kind of source it is. It will however not link with the C++ runtime library which is a problem here.

Comment: Hi AdrianTut, thanks a bunch on satisfying my curiosity for the warning on the enums.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It can link. Like I have shown. But this is not recommended.